# Powershell Error while executing Postgresl procedure

Tags: postgresql, powershell

I try to execute a procedure in postgres with powershell. The procedure has no parameters and can be succesfully called with call `public.waas_delete_empty_groups()`

To execute the code with powershell i used the code below

```
$Server = "localhost"
$Port  = "53722"
$DB = "mydb"
$Uid = "user"
$user = "wsmetauser"
$pass = "password"
$cnString = "DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)};DATABASE=" +$DB+ ";SERVER=" +$Server+ ";PORT=" +$Port+ ";UID=" +$Uid+ ";"


try{
    Write-Host "Start Delete Empty Groups"
    $Connection = New-Object -comobject ADODB.Connection
    $Connection.Open($cnString,$user,$pass)

    Write-Host "Setup the command object"
    $Command = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Command
    $Command.ActiveConnection = $Connection
    $Command.CommandType = 4  # adCmdStoredProc
    $Command.CommandText = "waas_delete_empty_groups"

    Write-Host "Execute procedure"
    $RecordSet = $Command.Execute()

    Write-Host "Close the connection"
    $Connection.Close()
    Write-Host "Finish Delete Empty Groups"
}
catch{
    Write-Host "Error - while executing"
    "?? Error in line $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber): $($Error[0])"
    exit 1
}
```

When i execute the above statement i get the following error back:

```
Start Delete Empty Groups
Setup the command object
Execute procedure
Error - while executing
?? Error in line 21: ERROR: waas_delete_empty_groups() is a procedure;
Error while executing the query
```

I realy don't know why this error occurs and how to solve this. Can you please help me out.

Manny tnanks!

Comment: In the `$Connection.Open()` line you have a variable `$user` which is not defined as far as I can see. Is that a typo?

Comment: I don't use Powershell but I do see this: `ERROR: waas_delete_empty_groups() is a procedure;`. I can see two reasons that happen; 1) A procedure needs to be called as in `CALL waas_delete_empty_groups`. So if a `SELECT` was used that would be a problem. 2) `$RecordSet = $Command.Execute()` Procedures don't have a `RETURN` so this could be a  problem. I would look at the Postgres log to see what is actually hitting the database and what error the server is throwing.

Comment: Hi Theo, no  adding the $user as a variable and assigning a value does not do the trick unfortuantly.

Comment: Hi Adrian when i put a call in the commandText ( call waas_delete_empty_groups i get the following error '''Error in line 22: ERROR: relation "call" does not exist'''

Comment: 1) Per my previous comment look at the Postgres log to see what is actually hitting the database. 2) Pretty sure `commandText = "call waas_delete_empty_groups"` got turned into `select call waas_delete_empty_groups()` by `$Command.Execute()`.